# Zend_Auth setCredentialTreatment

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, hash, zend-auth

I'm using `Zend_Auth` with `setCredentialTreatment` to set the hash method and salt. I see all examples doing something like this, where the `salt` seems to be inserted as a text.

> ->setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(CONCAT(?,salt))'

but my salt is stored in the database. I could retrieve it first then use it in `setCredentialTreatment` but is there a way I could define it directly as a field name, so `setCredentialTreatment` would know to get it from that field? sort of like the way we define the field name for the username or password

```
->setCredentialColumn('password')
```

A side issue I'm having is that I'd like to use SHA512 not SHA1. Is this possible or is it not available? All the examples I see using SHA1.

I should say I'm fairly new to zend and am porting an existing application, so please go easy on me with the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example you've given does use the salt as stored in the database. It will work as long as the salt is stored in each row in a field called 'salt'. If the salt was not in the DB and in a PHP variable instead, the code would be something more like:

```
->setCredentialTreatment("SHA1(CONCAT(?, '$salt'))")
```

As for using SHA512, this might be a little trickier. Assuming you're using MySQL, SHA1() in this case is a MySQL function, and MySQL does not have a function for SHA512 as far as I can tell, and neither does PHP (edit: I was wrong about the latter, see comments). So you'll have to implement your own PHP SHA512 function, load the salt for the user out of the DB first, hash the result and not do anything to the variable in setCredentialTreatment.

As the other answer suggested you might want to write your own Zend_Auth_Adapter for this. An auth adapter is a class that handles authentication, presumably at the moment you're using Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable. You can find some more info about auth adapters in the manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.introduction.html

Here's an example:

```
class My_Auth_Adapter extends Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable
{
    public function authenticate()
    {
        // load salt for the given identity
        $salt = $this->_zendDb->fetchOne("SELECT salt FROM {$this->_tableName} WHERE {$this->_identityColumn} = ?", $this->_identity);
        if (!$salt) {
            // return 'identity not found' error
            return new Zend_Auth_Result(Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND, $this->_identity);
        }

        // create the hash using the password and salt
        $hash = ''; // SET THE PASSWORD HASH HERE USING $this->_credential and $salt

        // replace credential with new hash
        $this->_credential = $hash;

        // Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable can do the rest now
        return parent::authenticate();
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP has SHA512 support through the hash extension: hash('sha512', 'some text to hash');

Comment: Actually in the original PHP I use `hash_hmac('sha512')`, but isn't defining a new adapter a bit of an overkill for this. How many lines of code would defining a new adapter be? I couldn't tell from the linked page because they're truncating the code.

Comment: It's the two-step process of having to load the salt first to do the hashing in PHP that makes your requirement a little custom. You can extend Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable so not much code should be required. I've edited my answer with an example to get you started - code is totally untested. Replace the $hash = ''; part with your hash_hmac() code.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `Zend_Auth_Adapter`.