# How setCredentialTreatment works in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can anyone tell me what is the use of following statement and how it works in Zend Framework?

> setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(CONCAT(?,`salt`))');

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725873/zend-auth-setcredentialtreatment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
                Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(),
                'users',
                'username',
                'password',
                "CONCAT('$this->_salt', sha(?))"
            );
            $authAdapter->setIdentity($username)
                ->setCredential($password);
```

Answer (score 4):

`setCredentialTreatment` tells the auth adapter how to check the user supplied password against the one in the database (or whatever passwords are being checked again). In your example, the `?` is the placeholder representing the password and `CONCAT()` and `SHA1()` are both database functions. So this example will append the salt to the user-entered password and then hash them using SHA1.

This will result in a database query that looks similar to this:

> SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'user@example.com' AND password = SHA1(CONCAT('password',salt))

You use `setCredentialTreatment()` to change how the passwords are checked. For example if your passwords are just straight MD5 hashes, you'd instead use:

```
setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');
```