# How setCredentialTreatment() works in Zend Framework 1.12?

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

Heloo
I am new to Zend,
I need to know how setCredentialTreatment() works.
I am having salt stored for each entry in database and salt is used to encrypt password some thing like this

```
    sha1($password.$salt);
```

Can there be solution for directly concatenating query for password with salt and comparing without fetchin prior to authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this:-

```
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
            Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(),
            'users',
            'username',
            'password',
            "CONCAT('$this->_salt', sha(?))"
        );
        $authAdapter->setIdentity($username)
            ->setCredential($password);
```

check this tutorial.
http://blog.richardknop.com/2009/06/user-login-and-authentication-with-zend_auth-and-zend_acl/

Answer (score 1):

`setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(CONCAT(?,salt));`

This question was already answered on SO:

[Zend_Auth setCredentialTreatment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725873/zend-auth-setcredentialtreatment)

[How setCredentialTreatment works in Zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701026/how-setcredentialtreatment-works-in-zend-framework)